# Baked Textures is not aligned as original texture

Tags: texture-baking

I'm new to blender and just need some help with Baking Textures.

I made a handrail in cycles and it renders perfectly with my unwrapped UV's and new material, with no issues what so ever, as shown below:

[image]

But as soon as I bake a diffuse map the material does not seam to align for some reason, as shown below:

[image]

[image]

I want to use blender to design static meshes in blender, bake textures and export them to Unreal Engine 4, but I'm stuck at the moment.

I deleted the UV's, made a new material and tried again, but I still have the same result...

Any help would be welcome, thank you in advance...:)

Comment: Is your new baked image then fed into your diffuse and set to use the UV mapping that aligned it correctly, or when originally set up did you use something other than that uv map as coordinate?

Comment: Object likely has 2 sets of UV coordinates - one used for creating material (on the first screenshot) and another - for rendering (on the second). Looks like rendering is done on wrong UV map, hence you get the difference. Make sure to set camera icon (used for render) for UV map you're baking from and select UV map you're baking to In UV maps list

Comment: Graig, I deleted my old material, created a new one and used the baked image on the diffuse BSDF. This seam to have solved the problem...:). Even worked perfectly in Unreal Engine 4...:). Thanks a lot guys, I'm still new at this so expect more questions...soon...XD.